# Reproducir en Segundo Plano Radio Streaming APP INVENTOR

Tags: app, appinventor

Buen día,
Estoy realizando una APP en APP INVENTOR la cual consiste en un reproductor streaming para una radio. Funciona en primer plano pero al entrar en segundo plano se apaga.
Agradecía vuestra ayuda

[image: Diseño de la app]

[image: los bloques "programados"]

como veréis no es código....

Comment: Hola Alexander, puedes [editar](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/59981/edit) tu pregunta para añadir el codigo referente a la reproduccion del audio de tu app?

Comment: Hola :) como veis la app esta hecha con un gestor de bloques...asi que código puro y duro no hay

Answer (score 1):

Hola puedes hacer esto de dos maneras, te lo indico lo que ami siempre me ha funcionado, ojo si quiero otro audio usaria otro control.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]